# A question about derived group and automorphism

Tags: group-theory

> Let $\alpha\in{\rm Aut}(G)$. Suppose that $x^{−1}x^\alpha \in Z(G)$ for all $x\in G$. Then $x^\alpha =x$
>   for all $x \in G′.$

**My attempt:**

$x ^{−1}x^\alpha$ commute with all elements in $G$, so $x^{−1}x^\alpha $ commute with $x$, that is to say $x^{−1}x^\alpha x= x x^{−1}x^\alpha =x^\alpha$.

But what should I do next?

Any hints or details will be sincerely appreciated!

**PS:**

[1] The exponential notation is for automorphism.

[2] It’s on page $26$ of [my textbook](http://www.math.ku.dk/~olsson/manus/GruFus/Kurzweil-Stellmacher_Theory%20of%20finite%20groups.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are too many $x$'s for comfort.

Hypotheses: $x,y\in G$; $x^{\alpha}=xu$ with $u\in Z(G)$; $y^{\alpha}=yv$ with $v\in Z(G)$.

Required: $[x,y]^{\alpha}=[x,y]$. (This will imply any product of commutators is fixed by $\alpha$.)

Proof:

$$
[x,y]^{\alpha}=
x^{-\alpha}y^{-\alpha}x^\alpha y^\alpha=
x^{-1}u^{-1}y^{-1}v^{-1}xuyv=
[x,y]$$
since $u,v$ are central.